# How to sync multiple S3 buckets using multiple AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am having trouble syncing two S3 buckets that are attached to two separate AWS accounts.

There are two AWS accounts - Account A which is managed by a third party and Account B, which I manage. I am looking to pull files from an S3 bucket in Account A to an S3 bucket in Account B.

Account A provided me the following instructions:

- In Account B, create a new IAM user called `LogsUser`. Attach the following policy to the user:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/12345-LogAccess-role"
            }
        ]
    }
```

- Configure the AWS CLI to update the config and credentials files. Specifically, the `~/.aws/config` file to look like:

  ```
  [profile LogsUser]
  role_arn = arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/12345-LogAccess-role
  source_profile = LogsUser
  ```

  And the `~/.aws/credentials` file to look like

  ```
  aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  ```
- From here, I am successfully able to query the log files in Account A's bucket using `$ aws s3 ls --profile LogsUser s3://bucket-a`.

I have set up `bucket-b` in Account B, however, I am *unable* to query any files in `bucket-b`. For example, `$ aws s3 ls --profile LogsUser s3://bucket-b` returns `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Access denied`.

Is there something additional I can add to the config file or my IAM policy to allow access to `bucket-b` using `--profile LogsUser` option? I can access `bucket-b` using other `--profile` settings, but am not looking to sync to the local file system and then to another bucket.

The desired results is to run a command like `aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a s3://bucket-b --profile UserLogs`.

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you want to copy “Account A” S3 bucket objects to “Account B” S3 bucket, follow below.

Create a policy for the S3 bucket in “account A” like the below policy. For that, you need “Account B” number, to find the B account number go to Support → Support center and copy the account number from there.

Setup “account A” bucket policy :

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B_NUMBER:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_A_BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_A_BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Log into “Account B” and create a new IAM user or attach the below policy for the existing user.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_A_BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_A_BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_B_BUCKET_NAME",
                "arn:aws:s3:::ACCOUNT_B_BUCKET_NAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Configure AWS CLI with “Account B” IAM user(Which you have created IAM with the above user policy)

```
aws s3 sync s3://ACCOUNT_A_BUCKET_NAME s3://ACCOUNT_B_BUCKET_NAME --source-region ACCOUNT_A_REGION-NAME --region ACCOUNT_B_REGION-NAME
```

This way we can copy S3 bucket objects over different AWS accounts.

If you have multiple awscli profiles, use `--profile` end of the command with profile name.

Answer (score 2):

Your situation is:

- You wish to copy from `Bucket-A` in `Account-A`
- The files need to be copied to `Bucket-B` in `Account-B`
- `Account-A` has provided you with the ability to assume `LogAccess-role` in `Account-A`, which has access to `Bucket-A`

When copying files between buckets using the `CopyObject()` command (which is used by the AWS CLI `sync` command), it requires:

- Read Access on the source bucket (`Bucket-A`)
- Write Access on the destination bucket (`Bucket-B`)

When you assume `LogAccess-role`, you receive credentials that have Read Access on `Bucket-A`. That is great! However, those credentials do not have permission to write to `Bucket-B` because it is in a separate account.

To overcome this, you should **create a Bucket Policy on Bucket-A that grants Write Access to `LogAccess-role` from `Account-B`**. The Bucket Policy would look something like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-A:role/12345-LogAccess-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

(You might need other permissions. Check any error messages for hints.)

That way, `LogAccess-role` will be able to read from `Bucket-A` and write to `Bucket-B`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to consider you to use AWS S3 bucket replication:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html

Answer (score -1):

**If you just want to list objects in `bucket-b`, do this.**

First make sure the LogsUser IAM user has got proper permission to access the `bucket-b` s3 bucket in Account B. You can add this policy to the user if not

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If there is permissions attached to the user, and if the Access keys and Secret Key stored in `~/.aws/credentials` stored as `[default]` belongs to LogsUser IAM user, you can simply list objects inside `bucket-b` with following command.
`aws s3 ls`

**If you want to run the command `aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a s3://bucket-b --profile UserLogs`, do this.**

Remember, we will be using temporary credentials created by STS after assuming the role with permanent credentials of LogsUser. That means the role in Account A should have proper access to both buckets to perform the action and the bucket(`bucket-b`) in another account (Account B) should have proper bucket policy to allow the role to perform S3 operations.

To provide permissions to the role to access `bucket-b`, attach following bucket policy to `bucket-b`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/12345-LogAccess-role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also in Account A, attach a policy to the role like below to allow access to S3 buckets in both the accounts.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Account A is managed by a third party data vendor and I am unable to attach policies there. Would this still be possible without? Else my approach would be to sync from bucket-a --> local file system --> sync to bucket-b.

Comment: To do that, the role ARN of Account A should have access to the S3 buckets. You download using the `--profile LogsUser`. And you put objects to `bucket-b` with proper permissions in Account B. Without the role having access to bucket in account A and role's trust relationship is given for Account B id, we have no way to do this.